# In which order should I import my Angular files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

**Angular app.js**

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module("myApp", [
            'ngRoute',
            'ui.tree',
            'ngAnimate',            
            'ngMaterial'
        ]);
})();
```

On the **index.html**, the order of libraries import is:

1. angular.min.js
2. angular-route.min.js
3. angular-ui-tree.min.js
4. jquery.min.js
5. bootstrap.min.js
6. angular-animate.min.js
7. angular-aria.min.js
8. angular-material.min.js

---

I'm getting this error:

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Comment: If it didn't matter, why would the app crash when you put the angular.min.js at the bottom of all scripts but fine at the beginning?  Do you know?

Comment: In the app.js, does it look fine? the order? Or does that don't matter either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order should be:

1. First import Angular (`angular.min.js`).
2. Import Angular files: controllers, services, directives...
3. Import others JS files

The order between Angular files does not matter (*eg: you can import services before controllers*).

---

In your case, a solution could be:

1. angular.min.js
2. angular-route.min.js
3. angular-ui-tree.min.js
4. angular-animate.min.js
5. angular-aria.min.js
6. angular-material.min.js
7. jquery.min.js
8. bootstrap.min.js

*Note: I don't see any controllers in your files, don't forget it!*

Comment: Thank you, I appreciated it!